# Typescript error when using inject to custom html head - property '$xxxx' does not exist on type 'xxxx'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

There's an error has occurred when I compile the Nuxt JS website.
This annoying error does not effect the site, but I don't no how to make it disappear.

Here's my code:
In inject.js file,I created a method which used to return some html head value.

```
const getHead = (meta) => {
  return {
    title, 
    meta:[
      ...
    ]
  }
}

export default ({}, inject) => {
  inject('getHead', { get: getHead })
}
```

I also add the file path into nuxt.config.file, so it can be used as following code:

```
...
export default class SomeClass extends Vue {
  ...
  head(){
    return this.$getHead.get(this.meta)
  }
  ...
}
```

Website can be created normally, but error shows up at the terminal:
***[Property '$getHead' does not exist on type 'SomeClass'.]***

I've found several ways to make this error disappear, such as "//ts-ignore" or change this to (this as any),but I'm not sure that these ways are safe to solve the problem.
Could somebody help?

Comment: This is covered by the documentation, https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/plugins.html

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for the comment. But I can't find the solution from the cookbook. It only mentioned the correct way to use plugin, and my plugin works fine. I just don't understand why the error still show up when it works fine.

Comment: Because you use TypeScript and not JavaScript. You need to type your code correctly in order for additional properties to be recognized by TS. I linked to the page that is relevant. It's right there, the thing with `inject` as in your case, https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/plugins.html#iii-combined-inject

Comment: @EstusFlask I tried but still not work. Even I copied the example code from plugin part of that webdite, and make it a TS file, then use it in vue file as a plugin. It still works fine, the plugin can output every string which I put it in. But the error is still there. The property does not exist error.

Comment: There should be at least `declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $getHead: { get: (meta: any): any }
  }
}` in your case, where `any` is something more meaningful. If it doesn't work, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem as it may depend on your setup.